# What data does clustering use from multiple raster files?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, clustering, erdas-imagine, image-classification

I currently have a series of rasters of the same area across different times. The data is categorical: the product of a supervised classification used on LANDSAT data run on ERDAS Imagine. Each classification used approx. 100 training areas, which is reflected in the attribute table of each raster, but the final results only have 10 classes, which is kind of represented in the attribute tables.

| Histogram | Red | Green | Blue | Opacity | Class_Names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8381 | 111 | 164 | 91 | 255 | LV12 |
| 2576 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 255 | VD5 |
| 4617 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 255 | VR5 |
| 19103 | 111 | 164 | 91 | 255 | LV8 |

Ultimately the real classes are represented by the **first character** of the Class_Names column, the rest is a byproduct of how I did the classification, which means that the rows across each raster are similar, but not the same. Each pixel has one class, and the whole dataset would represent how these pixels have changed class over time.

I want to treat my total dataset as an n-dimensional point cloud and run a cluster analysis, but I'm not sure how to engineer the features. Currently I'm using an **ISODATA** algorithm, both on ArcGIS Pro (ISO clusters + K-means) and ERDAS Imagine (Isodata Unsupervised Classification) and plan on later running an **ST-DBSCAN**, but only passing the rasters without modification.

I get results, but what are these results based on only the numerical data in the attribute tables, or something else?

Comment: Please decide whether it’s ArcGIS Pro or ERDAS Imagine that you wish to ask about in this particular question. If your question is platform agnostic then don’t mention a product and tag it as a [tag:gis-principle] instead.